# How to tell mvn:release to generate 2 different war filenames from the same project?

Tags: java, maven, tomcat7

I'm trying to generate automatically 2 different war filenames for my application myApp, this is because I want the filename named after the artifactId and version, and also I would like the same file copied under another filename. This because of how I deploy my application in Tomcat.

Thanks!

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin.html.

Comment: This plugin will embed tomcat to the war, right? How can I modify tomcat's configuration? datasources? etc

Comment: What? You can deploy your war to tomcat with this plugin.

Comment: But I can do that, now, that's not my problem. My problem is that tomcat doesnt take the META-INF/context.xml, so I have to change the war filename to the context with the "/" changed to "#"

Comment: See the `path` :) - http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#path.

Comment: what about this option ? http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.2/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html#contextFile what's the deployment mode?